# Passing List Values as Parameters

Tags: python

`list = ['12345','23456']`

I have a script `"test.py"`,I need to pass the values in a given list above as parameters to this script with `"pick"` as option, can anyone provide input on how this can be done?

Final goal is to run the script like the following:

```
 test.py pick 12345 23445
```

Comment: Does it need to support other options as well?

Comment: yes ,other options exist aswell

Comment: Ok.  So what about `test.py pick 1234 foo 456`?  Is it just looking for `pick` and then pulling all of the numbers after that?  Numbers and strings?  Are the numbers all integers?  Please define this a little better.

Comment: just looking for pick and all all integers

Comment: So, `test.py 1234 pick 456` should result in your script having `[1234, 456]` in it?

Comment: So basically you want to parse all the values passed as the cmd args and get it in to a list right ?

Comment: Also, are you opposed to a commandline like `test.py --pick 1234 456`?

Comment: @MuhammedKK - no I want to create a command as "test.py  pick 12345 23445"

Comment: How are you invoking the script ? are you using subprocess module ?

Comment: For this you can just concatenate strings right ?

Comment: @MuhammedKK - os.system("script2.py list") doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](/q/1009860/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subprocess

```
import subprocess

lst = ['12345','23456']
cmd = ['test.py', 'pick']
cmd.extend(lst)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Try this code. This will invoke the script test.py with args pick 12345 23456

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the arguments with sys.argv

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

If you want to run the script from another script you can use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

```
os.system("script2.py 1")
```

Comment: @nachholibre - test.py is being called within a script..I need to create a command as "test.py pick 1234 foo 456"

Comment: os.system is used for runnign a command...how to pass the values in list as arguements?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using **[sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)**, you can use **[getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html)**.